# ERROR: Could not install packages EnvironmentError: 'user/python3.8/site-packages/pip-20.2.3.dist-info/RECORD'

Tags: python, pycharm

which python
points to:

```
/Users/pmt/bin/python ---- should be python3.8 here.
```

Which is:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (20.2.4)
```

My `python v` however is:

```
Python 3.8.3
```

The pycharm project interpreter points to:

```
pmt/bin/python3.8
```

But for some reason the pip points to the old python library. How do you change this to point to the newer version?

This is already a `venv` so the `--user` arg is not helpful.

Below is when trying to install using pip3

```
(pmt) SAMUELs-MBP-2:pmt_model samuelwilson$ pip3 install dotenv
Collecting dotenv
  Using cached dotenv-0.0.5.tar.gz (2.4 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6j/0wtn_n6s53b94vmzxl7__5p40000gn/T/pip-install-qeixbwn3/dotenv/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6j/0wtn_n6s53b94vmzxl7__5p40000gn/T/pip-install-qeixbwn3/dotenv/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/6j/0wtn_n6s53b94vmzxl7__5p40000gn/T/pip-install-qeixbwn3/dotenv/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        setup(name='dotenv',
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/6j/0wtn_n6s53b94vmzxl7__5p40000gn/T/tmp375q4u0l', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please add to the full stack trace. The error message is not clear enough.

Comment: witch command are you running? its pip3 or pip ?

Comment: You probably need to use pip3, which OS are you in?

Comment: pip3 does not work. Pip3 gives the following error:

    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/6j/0wtn_n6s53b94vmzxl7__5p40000gn/T/tmp6hwitksh', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
@wviana

 Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

Try pip3 install python-dotenv